# HTML won't load images

Tags: html

So I have this HTML code:

`<img src="C:\Users\Nico\Documents\Sublime\Proyecto Tics\templates\logo.png" width="30" height="30">`

I've tried several things to make it work but it just won't load the image, the file path is correct and when I open the HTML file and get the image path then put it into chrome it opens the image perfectly. I've also tried using "logo.png" as the source but it wouldn't work either when I copied the image path it wasn't correct so ended up specifying the whole path. Whatever I specify as path doesn't seem to load.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use file system absolute path in html.

Refer [HTML File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: I've already tried that, tell me if I'm wrong but if the image is in the same folder as the HTML just writing the name of the file should work right?

Comment: That's right. It will work that  just writing the name of image file while image and html are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\` is not an actual path naming convention. It is just something Google Chrome has, try using a relative path.

Comment: I've tried using "logo.png" as the source and logo.png is in the same folder as the HTML file that should work right? But it isn't loading. :/

Comment: @nrivasm Hmm. Have you tried inspecting the elements to see if the `img` is at where it should be? Perhaps some css styling is making it invisible or off the screen?

Comment: It was where it was supposed to be, but anyways I figured it out. I'm using Python with Flask so I had to use url_for() so now it's kind of a dumb question, Thank you anyways :)